# How do I combine multiple nested angular flattening operators?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to use the results of Observables from multiple functions. Some need to run sequentially, and some not. Also, the result of the first one needs to be passed to some nested ones.

I've looked at multiple examples. However, I can't seem to figure out this particular combination. The syntax just confuses me.

Suppose you have the following functions where each return an Observable.

```
saveContactDetails(): Observable<ContactDetails> {
    // Returns single observable with single ContactDetails.
}

savePhones(contactId: string): Observable<Phone[]> {
    // Returns single observable with array of Phones.
}

saveEmails(contactId: string): Observable<Email[]> {
    // Returns single observable with array of Emails.
}

saveAll(): Observable<Contact> {
    // TODO: Can't figure out the login/syntax here.
}
```

Steps:

1. Call saveContactDetails(). Only after this completes, continue.
2. Using the result of saveContactDetails(), call savePhones() and saveEmails(). These two functions (and probably more) can run in parallel in no specific order.
3. Once all of the "child" Observables have completed, combine the results of all (parent and children) into a single Observable to return from saveAll().

I assume I need to use `concatMap` and `mergeMap` (or maybe `forkJoin`). But again, I can't seem to figure out the syntax using the online docs and examples.

Comment: Is there a reason all of these have to be observables? Could some of them be promises instead?

Comment: @chrismclarke Each of the functions are making separate API calls using http.post. and then map. So, somewhere along the line, I would need to handle the response of those. It's very easy for me to do return http.post(stuff).map(stuff).

Comment: You can convert those http posts to observables using `.toObservable()`. With that you can then use async/await to more easily manage waiting for operations to complete. In my opinion this is much simpler than handling lots of subscriptions and merging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like this.

you switchMap into a forkJoin of the ones that need input from the first. then you use an inner map to combine results from all 3.

```
  saveAll(): Observable<Contact> {
    return this.saveContactDetails().pipe(
      switchMap(contactDetails => forkJoin([
          this.savePhones(contactDetails.id), // however you get the id
          this.saveEmails(contactDetails.id)
        ]).pipe(
          map(([phones, emails]) => 
            Object.assign(contactDetails, {phones, emails})) // whatever your transform is
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: What's the purpose of switchMap() here? From my understanding, it means to stop everything. and start the next task. What am I forcing to stop?

Comment: switchMap cancels previous inner subscriptions upon a new outter emission, so that only one inner subscription is ever active.  In this case, since everything is single emission, no canceling will ever occur as there is only one emission.  switchMap, mergeMap and concatMap will all function exactly the same in the single emission case. However, semantically, I prefer switchMap as it indicates there will only be one active inner subscription ever.